# julia: recommended way to `include` files: list of includes in top-level file or nested includes?

Tags: include, julia, project-structure

What is the recommended way to `include` all the files for your project?

I have seen many examples that use a similar structure: an ordered list of `include` statements in a single top-level file (the file that defines a `Module`, or the "main" file in an application).

This also seemed to be the conclusion in the following thread:
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/best-practices-for-structuring-larger-projects/2652?u=nhdaly

---

However, `Lint.jl` seems to be very unhappy with this sort of project structure, complaining about the persistent `use of undeclared symbol`s.

Consider the following example:

```
# --- src/lib1.jl ---
struct MyStruct
    x::Int32
end

# --- src/lib2.jl ---
foo() = MyStruct(3)    # Lint.jl says: E321 MyStruct: use of undeclared symbol

# --- src/MyPackage.jl ---
module MyPackage

include("lib1.jl")
include("lib2.jl")

foo()

end
```

Of course, this code will work correctly, because `MyStruct` will be available before `lib2.jl` is compiled. But `Lint.jl` cannot know that. Even when using the Atom-integrated `linter`, it shows the same error.

So is it preferable to have *lib2.jl* `include("lib1.jl")` instead of all the includes in the top file? Or is it best to put them in *both* places, as you might for `C++` headers? I haven't seen a definitive recommendation for this anywhere, and I'd love if someone could provide one! :)

---

EDIT: changed file names to reflect a more typical julia directory structure.

Comment: Is there a strong reason for you not to use modules?

Comment: This seems like a bug in Lint.jl?

Comment: Huh, thanks. I've filed https://github.com/tonyhffong/Lint.jl/issues/248.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do a:

```
PkgDev.generate("MyPackage", "MIT")
```

This generates the whole folder structure. I put my Julia(.jl) files in the src folder and use 'using' to import functions in other Julia files in the same folder.